# shmget() gives EINVAL error

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I've been having a problem with shmget for a few hours now that I can't seem to figure out. Every time I try to make a call got `shmget()` it always returns with an EINVAL: "Invalid Argument" error.

The important parts of the code are as follows:

```
key_t generate_ipc_key()
{
    key_t ipc_key = ftok(__FILE__, KEY);
    if(ipc_key < 0) {
        perror("Failed to Generate IPC Key");
        exit(IPC_FAILURE);
    }

     return ipc_key;
}

int shared_memory_create(size_t memory_size)
{
    int shm_key = shmget(generate_ipc_key(), memory_size, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if(shm_key < 0) {
        perror("Failed to Create Shared Memory Key");
        exit(CREATE_FAILURE);
    }

    return shm_key;
}
```

The function is being called with:

```
shm_key = shared_memory_create(sizeof(data_t));
```

Where data_t is a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int hCount;
    int oCount;
    int bCount;
} data_t;
```

Also in case it helps the values for shared memory are:

```
kernal.shmmax = 33554432
kernal.shmall = 2097152
kernal.shmmni = 4096
```

I'm fairly new to C so I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing however I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

I'm not sure exactly what it was, ipcs showed no shared segments and I rebooted and now it works.

Comment: This may help. EINVAL != "Invalid argument".  EINVAL = A  new segment was to be created and `size < SHMMIN` or `size > SHMMAX`, or no new segment was to be created, a segment with given key existed, but size is greater than the size of that segment. man page. check the `memory_size` argument.

Comment: @Kira: I'm getting errno 22 which is EINVAL on my system.

Answer (score 2):

The man page says:

> ```
> EINVAL A new segment was to be created and size < SHMMIN or 
> size > SHMMAX, or no new segment was to be created, a 
> segment with given key existed, but size is greater than 
> the size of that segment.
> ```

So, check if any of these applies.
You can run the `ipcs` tool to list existing shared memory segments, and see if your program clashes with any of these. Note that the shared memory segments persists after your process ends.

Comment: I don't believe shmmni is the minimum size. It's the maximum number of shared memory segments that can be created. Regardless though, I agree with the rest of your premise and that they may need to increase the size.  The question is what that value should be.

Comment: I actually tried something to see if this was the issue and set it to close 2097152 and still no dice. I don't actually think there is a SHMMIN anymore, I tried looking and it apparently used to be 1 byte.

Comment: @spdaley Yes, you're right, it's the constant SHMMIN , and not kernel.shmmni